# Delete columns from BIRT report

Tags: birt

I have a BIRT Excel Report with 10 columns. I have a query which executes and brings the data for all the 10 columns.

However, based on one of the input parameters, i need to display just 8 columns. I am able to hide the remaining 2 columns but i would like to delete those 2 columns from the report so that user does not see the hidden columns.

I tried to change the query but i am unable to dynamically set the select parameters.

Is there a way either in Query or in BIRT to remove few columns based on an input condition.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete the columns, but it's sufficient to hide them dynamically using the column's visibility expression. You can add an aggregation to the table, using the MAX function for the column data (let's call it max_name).

E.g. if your table column shows the DS column NAME and you want to hide the column if NAME is empty for all rows:

Add an aggration (let's call it MAX_NAME) to the table, with the aggregation function MAX and the expression NAME. Then in the visibility expression of the table column, use !row["MAX_NAME"] as the expression.

Answer (score 0):

After drag and drop the dataset. Right click on column header and select the delete column option.